# Error "Cannot find symbol method charAt(int)"?

Tags: java, split, charat

```
System.out.println("Enter a sentence to get it translated into Pig Latin: ");

String sentence=kb.nextLine();

String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

char a=words.charAt(0);
```

Comment: `words` is a `String[]`. Array types only have the methods inherited from `Object`, ie. not `charAt(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that `words` is an array, and `charAt()` method is defined for `String`s. So you would like to use:

```
words[index].charAt(0)
```

instead, where `index` is the position of a `String` in the array.

Answer (score 0):

words is a string array. Try using words[index]. After splitting , the sub strings will be stored as following -

```
Enter = words[0]
a = words[1]
sentence = words[2]
to = words[3]
get = words[4]
it = words[5]
translated = words[6]
into = words[7]
Pig = words[8]
Latin: = words[9]
```

Accessing words[index].chartAt(0) will return the first character of respective sub string.